# Confusion in Recursion example

Tags: c++, recursion

I have an example of recursion in my lecture notes

```
void print(int n)
{
    if (n<1) {return;}
    print(n-1);
    cout<<n;
}
```

I have tried to implement this code in DEV C++ and in the debug mode I found that the print function calling itself after again and again until `n=0`. Then it went to `cout<<n` and start incrreament in `n` and shows output `1 2 3 4 5`
I don't understand why it shows this output, in my opinion it should just show `0`  at the output.

Comment: Cout is part of the loop and is executed after the call to print().

Comment: You should review your recursion lecture notes.

Comment: The function executes `print(n-1)`, and once `n-1` is printed, it then prints `n`. It's quite obvious really, think about it again. The function does not return once it's called itself, it returns when it hits a `return` statement or reaches the end

Comment: @kometen part of the loop? Then how it start showing from 1 to 5? every time when it went to print (n-1) the print function start again until the value of n=0. then it goes cout and shows the current value of n. isn't?

Comment: This is a good opportunity to get to know your debugger by stepping through this code.

Comment: ... or to use pencil and paper.

Comment: @juanchopanza nice suggestion I am doing that I couldn't found solution of this confusion there so I thought to discuss with experts

Comment: The answer is "because that is how recursion works". You can't expect people to post what would be the equivalent of your lecture notes as an answer here.

Comment: it works like after condition fails if(0<1) it goes to return and cout all the values from 1 to 5 by automatically incrementing?

Comment: @FrqKhan Just imagine you put five boxes on top of each other. Then you start by opening the top box which contains 1.

Answer (score 4):

The execution of your program (from top to bottom):

```
print (5)
    if (5<1) {return;} // <-- False; going on
    print (5-1) // print (4)
        if (4<1) {return;} // <-- False; going on
        print (4-1) // print (3)
            if (3<1) {return;} // <-- False; going on
            print (3-1) // print (2)
                if (2<1) {return;} // <-- False; going on
                print (2-1) // print (1)
                    if (1<1) {return;} // <-- False; going on
                    print (1-1) // print (0)
                        if (0<1) {return;} // <-- True; returning
                    cout << 1;
                cout << 2;
            cout << 3;
        cout << 4;
    cout << 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty simple. It is unwinding stack and prints local copy of n which is stored on a stack. Let's do it step by step:
print(3);
- 3 is not smaller than 1 so this function doesn't return
- Then in next line this function calls itself, but with decremented argument
so what happens then? Next stack frame is created with n-1 value which is COPIED, then the story is the same, it calls print until n = 0; copy of n each time!
So you have following stack on local n values:
1 <--next call is print(0) which returns doing nothing
2
3 <--we started here

So you then stack is unwound: and after it goes to next line after print (n-1), and in top frame the n == 1, then when next stack frame is unwound and local n copy == 2, then 3, what is sent to cout.

Is it clear now?

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation. That's means recursion creates a stack in the memory and keep checking the condition and keep making next stack frame until the condition is satisfied. Once the condition is true it will start from end to start..this is what I understand, is it right?

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `print()` the current value of the *local variables* (like `n`) is stored on a stack (the *call stack*) along with the position in the function you called it from.

Then, when you return from the function, the previous *local variables* are retrieved from the *call stack* and you return back in to the function in the position right after when you called it. Until you `return` as many times as you called.

So while you were calling `print()` the value of `n` was going down because each time you called `print()` with `n - 1` being set to the new parameter `n`, those values were being stored until you final get to `return;` and those values start popping off the *call stack* in *reverse order* that they were placed there until you return as many times as you called.

Comment: sorry couldn't understand this part
"until you return as many times as you called."

Comment: @FrqKhan When you `return` you go back to the place after you called it from so if you called it from within the function you go back into the function until you get to a point where you called it from a *different* function (like *main()*).